# React native App Signing is failing for my app update on a different machine

Tags: reactjs, native, android-app-signing

I have password for keystone and key for my react native app. I am trying to sign my app after I updated it on a different machine. I created a keystore file using my existing password for keystore and signed it. But when am uploading the app on playstore, it fails, it says the signing keys do not match and have different RSA values, I do not understand how to correct it. Kindly help.

Comment: If your app has already been released on Play Store, it must already have an upload key and a signing key. Upload key can be modified, but signing key is set in stone and no longer changes. It seems to me that you have recreated a new upload key but did not reset the old one. [Resetting the old upload key](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#reset) might help.

Comment: Actually sir, i have two separate project folders for the same project and different react native version --- one for rn.59 (older) and one for rn.63 (newer). I have the same my-release-key.keystore file in android/app. App signing config is same in gradle.properties and build.gradle folders for both version of projects.

I use gradlew assembleRelease to prepare .apk files.

But when i upload the app on play store for rn.59 folder it is done successfully and when i upload for rn.63,  it says the signing keys do not match and have different RSA values. I am very confused.

Comment: I think Play Store is treating your two versions as two separate apps. And they will need two separate keys. It seems to me that you want to update the rn.59 app with the rn.63 version. Perhaps you should build the new app under the same folder as the old one and then do an app update on Play Store.

Comment: I solved it myself ... thanks

Comment: How did you solved that? I am facing same problem. Please help.

Comment: In my case, I already had the password for keystore and key, and I was trying to regenerate it by following this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android. But when I was uploading the app on play store it was failing. So I used the already generated keystore file fo signing the app rather than regenerating it and it worked.